# Why does system PATH seem to be cleared?

Tags: windows-7, path, environment-variables

I have this strange situation at work where me and some other guys regularly have problems with our system PATH environment variable. Whenever that happens, we have problems like shortcuts that stop working, files don't open their associated program anymore, etc

The even stranger observation is that in the system environment variables dialog, I can see the system path is still set, however when opening a command prompt, `SET PATH` returns only the 'user defined' part of the path.

Any ideas on how to start investigating this issue?

Rebooting the PC fixes the problem.

In the event viewer, I see a 'SceCli' event ('Security policy in the Group policy objects has been applied successfully.'). Can this be related?

Comment: Have you done any research? Are the computers clean of viruses and malware? Have you run any diagnostics or `SFC /scannow` to verify system integrity?

Comment: @CharlieRB It's not that I don't want to do my research, just that I don't have any pointers as to where to get started. There's no viruses or malware in as far as that is a claim that can be made with certainty. Running the SFC scan now.